# Hadoop: Reduce-side join get stuck at map 100% reduce 100% and never finish

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm beginner with Hadoop, these days I'm trying to run
reduce-side join example but it got stuck: Map 100% and Reduce 100%
but never finishing. Progress,logs, code, sample data and
configuration files are as below:
Progress:

```
12/10/02 15:48:06 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/10/02 15:48:06 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/10/02 15:48:06 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
12/10/02 15:48:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201210021515_0007
12/10/02 15:48:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/10/02 15:48:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 66% reduce 0%
12/10/02 15:48:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/10/02 15:48:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 22%
12/10/02 15:48:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%

Logs from Reduce task:
2012-10-02 15:48:28,018 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1f53935
2012-10-02 15:48:28,179 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: ShuffleRamManager: MemoryLimit=668126400, MaxSingleShuffleLimit=167031600
2012-10-02 15:48:28,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for merging on-disk files
2012-10-02 15:48:28,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for merging in memory files
2012-10-02 15:48:28,203 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Thread waiting: Thread for merging on-disk files
2012-10-02 15:48:28,207 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Thread started: Thread for polling Map Completion Events
2012-10-02 15:48:28,207 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Need another 3 map output(s) where 0 is already in progress
2012-10-02 15:48:28,208 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-10-02 15:48:33,209 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Scheduled 1 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-10-02 15:48:33,596 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Scheduled 1 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-10-02 15:48:38,606 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201210021515_0007_r_000000_0 Scheduled 1 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-10-02 15:48:39,239 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: GetMapEventsThread exiting
2012-10-02 15:48:39,239 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: getMapsEventsThread joined.
2012-10-02 15:48:39,241 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Closed ram manager
2012-10-02 15:48:39,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Interleaved on-disk merge complete: 0 files left.
2012-10-02 15:48:39,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: In-memory merge complete: 3 files left.
2012-10-02 15:48:39,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 3 sorted segments
2012-10-02 15:48:39,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 3 segments left of total size: 10500 bytes
2012-10-02 15:48:39,314 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Merged 3 segments, 10500 bytes to disk to satisfy reduce memory limit
2012-10-02 15:48:39,318 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Merging 1 files, 10500 bytes from disk
2012-10-02 15:48:39,319 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
2012-10-02 15:48:39,320 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
2012-10-02 15:48:39,322 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 10496 bytes

Java Code:

public class DataJoin extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class MapClass extends DataJoinMapperBase {

        protected Text generateInputTag(String inputFile) {//specify tag
            String datasource = inputFile.split("-")[0];
            return new Text(datasource);
        }

        protected Text generateGroupKey(TaggedMapOutput aRecord) {//takes a tagged record (of type TaggedMapOutput)and returns the group key for joining
            String line = ((Text) aRecord.getData()).toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",", 2);
            String groupKey = tokens[0];
            return new Text(groupKey);
        }

        protected TaggedMapOutput generateTaggedMapOutput(Object value) {//wraps the record value into a TaggedMapOutput type
            TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable((Text) value);
            retv.setTag(this.inputTag);//inputTag: result of generateInputTag
            return retv;
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends DataJoinReducerBase {

        protected TaggedMapOutput combine(Object[] tags, Object[] values) {//combination of the cross product of the tagged records with the same join (group) key

            if (tags.length  != 2) return null;  
            String joinedStr = ""; 
            for (int i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
                if (i > 0) joinedStr += ",";
                TaggedWritable tw = (TaggedWritable) values[i];
                String line = ((Text) tw.getData()).toString();
                if (line == null)
                    return null;
                String[] tokens = line.split(",", 2);
                joinedStr += tokens[1];
            }
            TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable(new Text(joinedStr));
            retv.setTag((Text) tags[0]); 
            return retv;
        }
    }

    public static class TaggedWritable extends TaggedMapOutput {//tagged record

        private Writable data;

        public TaggedWritable() {
            this.tag = new Text("");
            this.data = null;
        }

        public TaggedWritable(Writable data) {
            this.tag = new Text("");
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Writable getData() {
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            this.tag.write(out);
            out.writeUTF(this.data.getClass().getName());            
            this.data.write(out);
        }

        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            this.tag.readFields(in);
              String dataClz = in.readUTF();            
              if ((this.data == null) || !this.data.getClass().getName().equals(dataClz)) {
                  try {
                    this.data = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(Class.forName(dataClz), null);
                    System.out.printf(dataClz);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }            
            this.data.readFields(in);
        }
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();

        JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, DataJoin.class);

        Path in = new Path(args[0]);
        Path out = new Path(args[1]);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

        job.setJobName("DataJoin");
        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(TaggedWritable.class);
        job.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
        JobClient.runJob(job); 
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),
                                 new DataJoin(),
                                 args);

        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

Sample data:

```
file 1: apat.txt(1 line) 4373932,1983,8446,1981,"NL","",16025,2,65,436,1,19,108,49,1,0.5289,0.6516,9.8571,4.1481,0.0109,0.0093,0,0
file 2: cite.txt(100 lines)
    4373932,3641235
    4373932,3720760
    4373932,3853987
    4373932,3900558
    4373932,3939350
    4373932,3941876
    4373932,3992631
    4373932,3996345
    4373932,3998943
    4373932,3999948
    4373932,4001400
    4373932,4011219
    4373932,4025310
    4373932,4036946
    4373932,4058732
    4373932,4104029
    4373932,4108972
    4373932,4160016
    4373932,4160018
    4373932,4160019
    4373932,4160818
    4373932,4161515
    4373932,4163779
    4373932,4168146
    4373932,4169137
    4373932,4181650
    4373932,4187075
    4373932,4197361
    4373932,4199599
    4373932,4200436
    4373932,4201763
    4373932,4207075
    4373932,4208479
    4373932,4211766
    4373932,4215102
    4373932,4220450
    4373932,4222744
    4373932,4225783
    4373932,4231750
    4373932,4234563
    4373932,4235869
    4373932,4238195
    4373932,4238395
    4373932,4248854
    4373932,4251514
    4373932,4258130
    4373932,4248965
    4373932,4252783
    4373932,4254097
    4373932,4259313
    4373932,4272505
    4373932,4272506
    4373932,4277437
    4373932,4279992
    4373932,4283382
    4373932,4294817
    4373932,4296201
    4373932,4297273
    4373932,4298687
    4373932,4302534
    4373932,4314026
    4373932,4318707
    4373932,4318846
    4373932,3773625
    4373932,3935074
    4373932,3951748
    4373932,3992516
    4373932,3996344
    4373932,3997657
    4373932,4011308
    4373932,4016250
    4373932,4018884
    4373932,4056724
    4373932,4067959
    4373932,4069352
    4373932,4097586
    4373932,4098876
    4373932,4130462
    4373932,4152411
    4373932,4153675
    4373932,4174384
    4373932,4222743
    4373932,4254096
    4373932,4256834
    4373932,4284412
    4373932,4323647
    4373932,3985867
    4373932,4166105
    4373932,4278653
    4373932,4194877
    4373932,4202815
    4373932,4286959
    4373932,4302536
    4373932,4020151
    4373932,4115535
    4373932,4152412
    4373932,4177253
    4373932,4223002
    4373932,4225485
    4373932,4261968
```

Configurations:

```
core-site.xml
<!-- In: conf/core-site.xml -->
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/your/path/to/hadoop/tmp/dir/hadoop-${user.name}</value>
<description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
<description>The name of the default file system. A URI whose
scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation. The
uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
the FileSystem implementation class. The uri's authority is used to
determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

mapred-site.xml
<!-- In: conf/mapred-site.xml -->
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>localhost:54311</value>
<description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
at. If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
and reduce task.
</description>
</property>

hdfs-site.xml
<!-- In: conf/hdfs-site.xml -->
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
<description>Default block replication.
The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
</description>
</property>
```

I've googled the answer and made some change in code or some configuration in (mapred/core/hdps)-site.xml files but I lost. I run this code in pseudo-mode. The join key from two files is equivalent. If I change the cite.txt file to 99 lines or lesser, It runs well while from 100 lines or above, it gets stuck like the logs shown. Please help me figure out the problem. I appreciate your explanation.

Best regards,
HaiLong

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Reduce class.
I faced similar problem which turned out to be a very silly mistake. Maybe this will help you out and solve the issue:

```
while (values.hasNext()) {
    String val = values.next().toString();
        .....
}
```

You need to add: `.next`